# Texture used by canvas.drawtext

Tags: android, android-layout

How does android renders a text on canvas? If i do

```
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(Width, Height
            , Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    canvas.drawText(text, x, y, textPaint);
```

Does it always use external texture for the text? What is the texture target for this?

Comment: texture? what do you mean?

Comment: @pskink it must be applying some texture or color to text.

Comment: this is done by passing `Paint` parameter to `drawText()` method

Comment: and if you need some shaders (instead of solid color) use `Paint#setShader()` method

Comment: @pskink does paint use surface textures?

Answer (score 1):

Bitmap resized = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, width, (bmp.getHeight() * width) / bmp.getWidth(), true);

```
            int oh1 = resized.getHeight();
            System.out.println("Resize height-->" + oh1 + "resize width-->" + resized.getWidth());
            Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
            matrix.postRotate(90.0f);
            Bitmap createBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(resized, 0, 0, resized.getWidth(), resized.getHeight(), matrix, true);
            Bitmap mutableBitmap = createBitmap.copy(Config.ARGB_8888, true);
            Canvas canvas = new Canvas(mutableBitmap);
            Paint paint = new Paint();
            paint.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
            paint.setTextSize(20.0f);
            paint.setTextAlign(Align.CENTER);
            simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
            String dateTime = simpleDateFormat.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
            System.out.println(dateTime);
            canvas.drawText(dateTime, 150.0f, 100.0f, paint);
```